# How to run Bash Script in background

Tags: bash, ssh, remote, background-process, nmap

I am remotely connected to a system using `ssh` and want to run `nmap` on a system from there. But every 5 minutes, my SSH connection breaks and so the process running on my shell stops.

How can I run `nmap` in the background so that any SSH session can interact with the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `nohup`. But `screen` is what you are probably looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The task you are describing can unfortunately not accomplished by simply sending the process in the background on the remote machine. Even if you started it with

```
user@remote~$ ./script &
```

it would get killed if your SSH connection breaks.

Instead, you will have to use a terminal multiplexing software such as [`tmux`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/tmux/info) or [`screen`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/gnu-screen/info) (availability may depend on your specific OS).